# Is this query iteration possible

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the below table running

```
--TYPE-- --VALUE--  --PLACE--
 type1      10        place1
 type2      20        place1
 type3      30        place1
 type1      40        place2
 type1      40        place2
 type2      60        place2
 type2      60        place2
 type3      70        place2
 type3      70        place2
```

I need to output all of this data in the following format.

```
Place1 -> Type1 -> 10
Place1 -> Type3 -> 20
Place1 -> Type3 -> 30
Place2 -> Type1 -> 80
Place2 -> Type3 -> 120
Place2 -> Type3 -> 140
```

I need to iterate through the places but also sum up the values for each type. There could be many rows that contain the same type and same place but different values so need to be summed.

I have been racking my head for hours trying to think if this is even possible.
Any help / advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that:

```
SELECT place, type, SUM(VALUE) AS sum FROM table GROUP BY place, type ORDER BY sum ASC
```

Comment: perfect, though I think he may want to order by place desc, type desc instead of sum

Comment: From the example it seems like he wants to order by sum incrementally, but yeah.